# Create a link to another page in hot towel

Tags: hottowel

How to create a link to another page in hot towel ?

I know that to add a link to the menu, I have to add it here :

```
function boot() {
    router.mapNav('home');
    router.mapNav('details');
    router.mapNav('about');
    log('Hot Towel SPA Loaded!', null, true);
    return router.activate('home');
}
```

But how to link to one of these links from an html page ?

Comment: if using an anchor tag <a href='#/details'>Details</a> or if using code router.navigateTo('#/details')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within your app, your link would be something like:

```
<a href='#/details'>go to details</a>
```

Otherwise you can use Durandal from your view model:

```
router.navigateTo('#/details');
```

Answer (score 1):

For ex, if you want to add Session Link, add the javascript file in App/viewmodel/session.js Then add the html file in App/views/session.html and then in shell.js

```
 function boot() {
        router.mapNav('home');
        router.mapNav('details');
        router.mapNav('session');
        log('Hot Towel SPA Loaded!', null, true);
        return router.activate('home');
    }
```